# Font warning: Why do size substitutions happen?

Tags: fonts

I apologize if this question isn't allowed... I'm trying to understand some warnings output in the LaTeX log file after compiling (with xelatex). One has to do with font sizes:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <30> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line XYZ.
```

I would like to understand what is happening here and why it is happening. I'm not loading this font "OMS/cmsy" anywhere... where is LaTeX getting it from? Also, why does it frequently substitute such strange sizes (e.g. 24.88)?

The same things happen with other fonts I do not explicitly load, such as OT1/cmr or OMS/cmsy... why is LaTeX using these fonts and substituting sizes for them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LaTeX is quite old, and at the begin fonts were only used in discrete size to save memory and disc space. So a lot of the older font definitions files contain instruction to use font only at this sizes and they trigger a size substituation if another size is requested. E.g. in OT1cmr.fd you can find:

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}%
     {<5><6><7><8><9><10><12>gen*cmr%
      <10.95>cmr10%
      <14.4>cmr12%
      <17.28><20.74><24.88>cmr17}{}
```

The numbers are multiple of 1.2: `12=10*1.2`, `14.4= 1.2*12`, `17.28 = 1.2*14.4`.

I don't know where you load such fonts as you didn't provide an example, but you can avoid most of the messages by loading fix-cm:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} %avoid size substituation
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{30pt}{30pt} \selectfont xxx %
\end{document}
```

Comment: But latex is younger than me, so how can it be old?